# How can I replace everything inside an href with JavaScript regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

My text is something like:

```
<a href="http://example.com/test this now">Stuff</a>

More stuff

<a href="http://example.com/more?stuff goes here">more</a>
```

I want to replace what's inside the `href` with a function that will URL Encode just the URL portion.

How would I go about this?

**UPDATE**
Here's what I've tried:

```
postdata.comment.content = postdata.comment.content.replace(/href=\"(.+?)\"/g, function(match, p1) {
    return encodeURI(p1);
});
```

Does not do what I would have hoped.

Expected result is:

```
<a href="http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Ftest%20this%20now">Stuff</a>

More stuff

<a href="http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fmore%3Fstuff%20goes%20here">more</a>
```

Comment: Which one of the two links do you want to modify? What's the expected result, exactly?

Comment: `$(pattern).attr('href', 'http://youpi.test/bidule');`

Comment: No jQuery. I need pure JS

Comment: Are the anchor tags rendered in the DOM before you access them or are you trying to manipulate in-memory strings? I am 99% sure that [Oriole's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36986707/2191572) is the way to go and not the one you've accepted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The regex is matching the complete attribute `href="...."`, however, the replacement is only done by the encoded URL and use `encodeURIComponent()` to encode complete URL.

```
var string = '<a href="http://example.com/test this now">Stuff</a>';

string = string.replace(/href="(.*?)"/, function(m, $1) {
    return 'href="' + encodeURIComponent($1) + '"';
    //      ^^^^^^                     ^
});
```

```js
var str = `<a href="http://example.com/test this now">Stuff</a>

More stuff

<a href="http://example.com/more?stuff goes here">more</a>`;

str = str.replace(/href="(.*?)"/g, (m, $1) => 'href="' + encodeURIComponent($1) + '"');

console.log(str);
document.body.textContent = str;
```

Comment: Can I use this to replace ALL links?

Comment: @Shamoon Yes, using `g` flag on regex will replace all the links as you can see in the demo I've created.

Answer (score 6):

For the encoding, you can use `encodeURIComponent`:

```js
var links = document.querySelectorAll('a');
for(var i=0; i<links.length; ++i)
  links[i].href = encodeURIComponent(links[i].href);
```

```html
<a href="http://example.com/test this now">Stuff</a>
More stuff
<a href="http://example.com/more?stuff goes here">more</a>
```

If you only have a HTML string instead of DOM elements, then use [don't use regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1529630). Parse your string with a DOM parser instead.

```js
var codeString = '<a href="http://example.com/test this now">Stuff</a>\nMore stuff\n<a href="http://example.com/more?stuff goes here">more</a>';
var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(codeString, "text/html");
var links = doc.querySelectorAll('a');
for(var i=0; i<links.length; ++i)
  links[i].href = encodeURIComponent(links[i].href);
document.querySelector('code').textContent = doc.body.innerHTML;
```

```html
<pre><code></code></pre>
```

And note that if you encode the URL entirely, it will be treated as a relative URL.

Comment: Instead of `new DOMParser().parseFromString(codeString, "text/html");`, you could do `(function(){ this.innerHTML = html; [...] }).bind(document.createElement('div'))(html)` (which MAY be a bit faster)

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Yes, but only if the string is trusted. Try your approach with `'<img src="//" onerror="alert(\'You are pwned!\')" />'`

Comment: Very nice point. 20 upvotes for you! I had no idea that Javascript would run when no element is added to the DOM.

Answer (score 4):

Where is this running? If you have a DOM, then you are MUCH better off using a DOM loop over document.links or document.querySelectorAll("a") than regex on HTML. 
Also you likely do not want to encode EVERYTHING, only the search part

```
var allLinks = document.querySelectorAll("a");
for (var i=0;i<allLinks.length;i++) {
   var search = allLinks[i].search;
   if (search) {
     allLinks[i].search="?"+search.substring(1).replace(/stuff/,encodeURIComponent("something"));
   }
}
```

In case you really DO want to have encoded hrefs then

```
for (var i=0;i<allLinks.length;i++) {
   var href = allLinks[i].href;
   if (href) {
     allLinks[i].href=href.replace(/stuff/,encodeURIComponent("something"));
   }
}
```

Comment: It's pretty clear from the question OP wants to encode the *whole* URL.

Comment: Yes, `http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Ftest%20this%20now` is probably worthless for most things but it's what OP wants.

Comment: What he thinks he wants. Have a search for "what is the X/Y problem" anyway - updated to include href

Answer (score 4):

*Disclaimer:  Don't use regex to parse HTML*
(too many reasons to list here..)

But, if you insist, this might work.

Find `/(<[\w:]+(?:[^>"']|"[^"]*"|'[^']*')*?\shref\s*=\s*)(?:(['"])([\S\s]*?)\2)((?:"[\S\s]*?"|'[\S\s]*?'|[^>]*?)+>)/`

Replace `$1$2` + someEncoding( $3 ) + `$2$4`

Expanded

```
 (                             # (1 start)
      < [\w:]+ 
      (?: [^>"'] | " [^"]* " | ' [^']* ' )*?
      \s 
      href \s* = \s* 
 )                             # (1 end)
 (?:
      ( ['"] )                      # (2)
      (                             # (3 start)
           [\S\s]*? 
      )                             # (3 end)
      \2 
 )
 (                             # (4 start)
      (?: " [\S\s]*? " | ' [\S\s]*? ' | [^>]*? )+
      >
 )                             # (4 end)
```

Comment: "too many reasons to list here" *the song of re̸gular exp​ression parsing will exti​nguish the voices of mor​tal man from the sp​here I can see it can you see ̲͚̖͔̙î̩́t̲͎̩̱͔́̋̀ it is beautiful t​he final snuffing of the lie​s of Man ALL IS LOŚ͖̩͇̗̪̏̈́T ALL I​S LOST the pon̷y he comes he c̶̮omes he comes the ich​or permeates all MY FACE MY FACE ᵒh god no NO NOO̼O​O NΘ stop the an​*̶͑̾̾​̅ͫ͏̙̤g͇̫͛͆̾ͫ̑͆l͖͉̗̩̳̟̍ͫͥͨe̠̅s ͎a̧͈͖r̽̾̈́͒͑e n​ot rè̑ͧ̌aͨl̘̝̙̃ͤ͂̾̆ ZA̡͊͠͝LGΌ ISͮ̂҉̯͈͕̹̘̱ TO͇̹̺ͅƝ̴ȳ̳ TH̘Ë͖́̉ ͠P̯͍̭O̚​N̐Y̡ H̸̡̪̯ͨ͊̽̅̾̎Ȩ̬̩̾͛ͪ̈́̀́͘ ̶̧̨̱̹̭̯ͧ̾ͬC̷̙̲̝͖ͭ̏ͥͮ͟Oͮ͏̮̪̝͍M̲̖͊̒ͪͩͬ̚̚͜Ȇ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝S̨̥̫͎̭ͯ̿̔̀ͅ*

Comment: that's the only reason you need

Answer (score 2):

Your *expected* string `"http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Ftest%20this%20now"` corresponds to this operation `encodeURIComponent("http://example.com/test this now")`, but not with `encodeURI` function:

```
var str = '<a href="http://example.com/test this now">Stuff</a>More stuff<a href="http://example.com/more?stuff goes here">more</a>';
str = str.replace(/href=\"(.+?)\"/g, function (m, p1) {
    return encodeURIComponent(p1);
});

console.log(str);
// <a http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Ftest%20this%20now>Stuff</a>More stuff<a http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fmore%3Fstuff%20goes%20here>more</a>
```